# eventEmmiter with reading textfile

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a multi-line text file that contains the same data, for example: pepperoni pizza
pizza margarita etc. I want to make eventEmmiter, which, when reading this file, performs certain events. for example, if there is peperoni in the text, then the peperoni event is output and then the result event. I can't figure out how to bind eventemmiter and reading a file
this is how i tried to do

```
const fs = require('fs');
const EventEmitter = require('events');
let readstream = fs.createReadStream('text.txt', {encoding: 'utf8'});
readstream.on('data', (data)=> {
         data.toString();
    })

const emitter = new EventEmitter();
emitter.on('result', (data)=> {
    console.log(`enjoy your pizza`);
})
emitter.on('peperoni', (data)=> {
    if (data.includes("peperonu")==1) {
        console.log(`event peperoni is ${data}`);
        emitter.emit('result', data);
    }
})
emitter.on('margarita', (data)=> {
    if (data.includes("margarita")==1) {
        console.log(`event margarita is ${data}`);
        emitter.emit('result', data);
    }
})
emitter.emit('peperoni', readstream.on);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) that will return a readable interface yielding each line. In my example, I'm emitting a `result` event but you can register & change this event to suit your needs.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const readline = require("readline");

const emitter = new EventEmitter();

emitter.on("result", (line) => {
    console.log(line);
});

async function main() {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream("text.txt", { encoding: "utf8" });

    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: readStream,
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    for await (const line of rl) {
        if (line.includes("margarita")) {
            console.log(`event margarita is ${line}`);

            emitter.emit("result", line);
        }

        if (line.includes("peperoni")) {
            console.log(`event peperoni is ${line}`);

            emitter.emit("result", line);
        }
    }
}

main();
```